# фреймворки для android

Tags: android

Чем отличается Android Studio от фреймворков (RxAndroid, Otto, Guave и прочие)?

Для чего нужны эти фреймворки? Мне объязательно надо знать эти фреймворки, или Android Studio достачно? Что конкретно мне нужно, чтобы стать хорошим Андроид разработчиком?

Answer (score 3):

> Смысл фреймворка – увеличить производительность, уменьшив затраты
>   усилий на разработку. В идеале они экономят разработчикам время на то,
>   чтобы заняться реально важными при разработке приложения
>   вопросами.([Хабрахабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/265261/))

Добавлю, что некоторые из них также позволяют писать под Android на языках программирования отличных от Java. Например, Xamarin или FireMonkey.

Для того чтобы профессионально разрабатывать под Android вполне достаточно изучить Android SDK, с которым собственно и работает Android Studio.

С определённой точки зрения, это даже предпочтительнее. Android SDK разрабатывается и развивается вместе с платформой. Если фреймворк перестанет обновляться, проект обречён на определённое технологическое отставание и, если впоследствии ситуация не изменится, предстоит миграция проекта на другой, более современный, фреймворк или "чистый" Android SDK.

Вообще, все фреймворки это, по сути, своего рода надстройки над "чистым" Android SDK. Однако, даже если Вы работаете с каким-либо фреймворком и это Ваш основной инструмент, иметь представление о Java и Android SDK всё равно потребуется, так как не всегда возможности платформы Android покрываются функционалом конкретного фреймворка.

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio - это IDE - интегрированная среда разработки. В ней ПИШУТ код, в том числе и фреймворков.

Фреймворк - это программная платформа (грубо говоря большой набор классов, комплексно решающий определенные задачи) Например, Android - фреймворк.

То, что вы перечислили (RxAndroid, Otto, Guava) - это библиотеки (Хотя RxJava и можно причислить к фреймворкам по некоторым признакам). Данные продукты служат для упрощения\ускорения разработки, когда вместо того, чтобы писать какие то модули самостоятельно вы пользуетесь готовыми библиотеками.

Для того, чтобы стать хорошим разработчиком вам нужно очень много читать, как минимум.

PS: Весь ваш вопрос несколько абсурден и выглядит примерно так на бытовом уровне - чем отличается стол инженера от завода (Polo, Land Cruiser, Приора и прочие)